# Elasticsearch: Search across _all with different queries

Tags: date, search, elasticsearch, field

I have a situation where I have one search box where a user enters key words. Depending on those key words I need to perform different queries. For example if a user enters 'John Doe 3/13/1984' I would need the 'John Doe' section to do the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": {
               "query": "John Doe",
               "operator": "and",
               "fuzziness": 1,
               "prefix_length": 1
           }
        }
    }
}
```

and for the '3/13/1984' input it would need to do the query

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "dateofBirth": {
        "lte": "March 13, 1984",
        "gte": "03/13/1984",
        "format": "MM/dd/yyyy||MMMM dd, yyyy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The high level question is how are you able to search across _all with one query but depending on what the input is at the time to do separate queries? I hope this makes sense and that some people have come across this same problem.